# Sorting an array of strings alphabetically in scala

Tags: arrays, string, scala, sorting

I am trying to sort an Array of Strings in alphabetical order using scala. The Strings are passed in an array when the method is called. The method must also return an array with the sorted Strings. How would I do this?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 6):

You just need to call `array.sorted`.